# Where are the Icons included with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, icons

I heard that Visual Studio came with an Image Library, but I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In VS 2008 they're under:

PROGRAMFILES\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary\1033

Answer (score 134):

From Visual Studio 2012 onward, the icons are downloadable separately from Visual Studio:

- [The Visual Studio Image Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/the-visual-studio-image-library)

The library contains application images that appear in Microsoft Visual Studio, Microsoft Windows, the Office system, and other Microsoft software.

The download [wasn't initially available](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758881/image-library-missing-from-visual-studio-2012) when Visual Studio 2012 launched.

Comment: Any possibility to get older Icon Libraries without having to install the related version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @ZapStorm: You could probably use [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557.aspx) to extract the CAB files from the MSIs and something like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to identify the right one and extract the icon files (or zip file?) from it.

Comment: Still very elaborate but okay, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 13):

Visual Studio 2010:

PROGRAMFILES\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033\VS2010ImageLibrary.zip

Unzip and enjoy

Answer (score 10):

VS2012 Modern Image Library

Microsoft published on 3/13/2013 about Visual Studio Image Library Version 2012 and you can download it from the page

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825

Comment: @BlakeNiemyjski Looks like they did update it for 2013.

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio 2005:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\VS2005ImageLibrary\VS2005ImageLibrary

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2019 Community

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Assets`

Comment: I have the Professional version of 2019 and this folder only contains 4 different icons. Also the downloads from Microsoft are plain b&w tiny icons. What am I missing?

Comment: @Richard No idea what you're downloading, but this link worked for me: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825 - also, VS icons are 16x16 so it's normal for them to be "tiny".

Comment: Indeed there are no icons, that is *.ico   You can still use them, but if you're looking for application icons (to show up on the desktop), you need to create your own, find another source, or buy them (you can also extract from dll and exe files from other programs, though this may be a license violation).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 for windows phone

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons