# List of icons for Visual Studio Add-ins

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, add-in

I am cooking up a quick Visual Studio 2008 add-in.  One of the key commands is to place a menu entry under the Tools menu:

```
Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "MyAddin", "My Addin", 
     "Executes the command for MyAddin", true, 
     59, 
     ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported
          +(int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, 
     (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, 
     vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);
```

One of the parameters is 59 (6th parameter), which refers to the icon ordinal that a plugin can use.  Apparently there are hundreds available.

Is there a complete list of icons somewhere so that I can actually see what they look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are the Icons included with Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301968/where-are-the-icons-included-with-visual-studio)

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - It is in no way a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the list:

http://www.kebabshopblues.co.uk/2007/01/04/visual-studio-2005-tools-for-office-commandbarbutton-faceid-property/

For instance, the integer 59 represents a smiley face.