# How can I revert the file icons used in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I want to use VS2013, but I want it to LOOK as much as possible like VS 2010.
The theme isn't too bad, but the file icons are annoying.

I've gotten hold of the new and old images (See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301968/where-are-the-icons-included-with-visual-studio)), but is there any way that I can convince VS 2013 to use the old ones?

I've tried putting the unzipped folder in the appropriate place, and editting the images but that doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Those icons are for use with YOUR applications, the ones you make to include in your toolbars, buttons etc.  They have nothing to do with the images for VS.  The images used in Visual Studio's toolbars are compiled resources and can't be changed.

The images in 2013 are much better than the images in 2012 so MS did listen many complaints from developers, for what it is worth.