# Where are the Visual Studio 2022 C icons located?

Tags: visual-studio

I recently installed Visual Studio 6.0 and it's replaced all the icons in Windows 10 with the old Win9X style. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167277/how-to-extract-visual-studio-project-template-icons) topic which shows the locations of the C# and VB icons, but what about the C icons?

**SOLVED**

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\vcpackages\VCProject.dll
```

Comment: "I recently installed Visual Studio 6.0" _why_?

Comment: An old project needed compiling using the old compiler for speed comparison.

Comment: That's fine, but you should do it inside a VM on a period-correct OS with a compatible Windows SDK installed (i.e. Windows 2000). You won't get very far with installing it on Windows 10, in fact I'm surprised it installs at all.