# Visualstudio choosing Application Icon

Tags: icons, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

About a year ago I wrote a C++ app in VisualStudio 2019.
I changed the icon of the .exe file by choosing from the default icons provided by VisualStudio. As far as I can remember there were more than 50 icons to choose from. All of them had similar, gray, minimalistic style, see below [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlYhc.png)

I searched the *Visual Studio 2022 Image Library* but couldn't find the icon I was looking for.
I think there was a very easy way (like some menu) inside VS which allowed me to choose a icon from the default ones. In VS2022 I only found a file chooser dialog...

I searched in the Common7 path, but only found `Common7\IDE\Assets` which only contains very few pngs.

Is there a path were those default icons/images reside or do I have to install something (Extension, Component ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can download them from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/the-visual-studio-image-library?view=vs-2022

See also [Where are the Icons included with Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301968/where-are-the-icons-included-with-visual-studio)